# How to build on TFS a c++ native project targeting Win10 platform

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

A migrated VS2013 c++ native project to vs2015 targeting Windows 10 (instead of Win 8.1) gives me some issues on the TFS Build Server. I use TFS2013 and the Release12 Build Process Template.

The TFS2013 is installed on a Win10 machine with VS2015 installed on it.

When I run the build the build throws an exception in one of the tasks from the target files saying that it can't compare the numeric number 10.0.4 ... something, because that is the Target Platform set in the native project file. Obviously this is not a number with it's two dots in the version number.

Am I doing something wrong? The TF Build uses MS Build v12 by the way and not the MS Build v14 that ships with VS2015. Do I need to change to MSBuild v14 to make this work? If yes, how can I actually change the used MSBuild version?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information about your exception and build file?
I'm not sure is it realed to MSBuild V14.
If You want to amend the build templates to point to MS Build version 14.0. You can folow below steps :

1. Use the Default Template (TfvcTemplate.12.xaml) in Visual Studio
2. Open the template and find the Run MSBuild for Project MSBuild activity.
3. Set ToolVersion to "14.0".
4. Set ToolPath to target to MSBuild14 (by default: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin").
5. Check in this build process template and re-queue the build.
   [image]

If you still have the same problem after you use MSBuild V14.0.
There is a realted version with 10.0.4... in VS2015. MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1 .It means the minimum visual studio version supported in VS2015. Maybe you build a file that created by a visual studio which version is earlier than the version10.0.40219.